# When using msdeploy for a sync can I ask it to ignore the systeminfo.xml?

Tags: iis, msdeploy

High level overivew of the steps involved:

1. Use MSDeploy to create a deployment package
2. Edit the contents of the zip package and then repackage it
3. Deploy to a remote server fails as the values in the systeminfo.xml are different to what it expects i.e. the list of `<installedComponentInfo>` must be different from the source to the destination server. If I manually edit the xml and remove all the `<installedComponentInfo>` re-zip the package and try again it works fine.

So can I tell MSDeploy to ignore the systeminfo.xml file when it does the deploy step above or any other suggestions around the `<installedComponentInfo>`?

The error is:

```
Warning: Skipping source dirPath (c:\blah\blah\Package) because of rule SkipInvalidSource.

The Zip package 'c:\blah\blah\Package\MyPackage.zip' could not be loaded.
```

And nothing gets deployed to the remote IIS server.

I have done several searches on this so any answers on why the systeminfo.xml is causing an issue or more importantly a workaround to ignore it please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the `SkipInvalidSource` rule.

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:webServer -dest:webServer,computerName=Server2 -disableRule:SkipInvalidSource
```

I am curious why you are manually editing the package. You can use MSBuild to customize the package or create a custom package yourself using MSDeploy.exe directly.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/05/19/extending-the-webdeploy-manifest/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569019(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Hi chief, I tried disabling SkipInvalidSource but no joy. I have to edit the package to update config files but for this given project there is no config updates so just un-zipping, making a copy of files and re-zipping is somehow making the .zip corrupt and it 'could not be loaded'.

For this given case, as there's nothing to update, I've decided to ignore the repackaging step but very strange why a copy caused it to be invalid...

Comment: Not sure why the skip didn't work but this is a security measure they created so someone couldn't hack/change your package unbeknownst to you.  You should use WebDeploy Parameterization instead to update config (or any file really) during the deployment process. http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2014/09/08/parameterizationpreview-visual-studio-extension/

Comment: Sorry chief, I'm not in a position to re-write the whole deployment process :(
Thanks anyway.